# How do you enable pinball arcade season pass on ps3

Tags: psn

I just bought "Pinball Arcade Season Two Pass" and I also received the email confirmation from PSN. But when I start up the game all the tables in season 2 are still locked. If I go to "My tables" I only have the 4 core tables; "Black Hole", "Ripley's Believe It or Not", "Tales of the Arabian Nights" and "Theatre of Magic". This is what I have tried so far, none of them worked:

- Buying season two pass from within the game. Here I can only select "Rate" and "Recommend", not "Buy"
- Downloading the package from PSN. When I press "Download" on the package page the screen goes black for a second and then returns to the package page. I suspect that this might be the cause of my issue.
- Re-installing the game. Here the game immediately starts to download from PSN when I press "Download" as opposed to when I tried downloading the package alone.
- Restarting the PS3.
- Searching through the game options for any possible "unlock" feature

In addition, when I try and browse the season 5 tables from within the game I am told "All currently available tables purchased", yet on PSN I can buy the season five pass as if I did not own them. Am I missing something obvious here - is the game broken somehow or is it an issue with PSN? How hard can it be to buy a simple update for a PS3 game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out with the help of a friendly PSN supporter. You are suppose to download the table bundles individually. Once you have bought the season pass all the associated table bundles are marked as free for download on PSN.